# Draw only the top of the boundary of a function in Plot3d

Tags: graphics, color

So currently I have

[image: Graph]

via combining 3 Plot3D's in a show. My question is how can I make it so that the ONLY portion of that border highlighted green, is the "curving portion" in the xy plane, rather than the whole border...?

Related Code:

Code is a variation on

```
Show[Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x + y < 1]], 
 Plot3D[{0}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x + y < 1], 
  BoundaryStyle -> Green]
 ]
```

Comment: ...... I just want to change which points are colored Green... right now all of the borders of the functions are colored Green. I don't think? RegionPlot is relevant

Comment: Could you post the code for the plot so that we can see how the green curve is generated in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

```
 Show[Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x + y < 1]], 
 Plot3D[{0}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x + y < 1],
 Exclusions -> {{x + y == 1}}, 
  ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Directive[Thick, Red]}], BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Uhm that's Sec[x], not 1-x . also can I just put the function in to extend this for any function, e.g. a complication combination of x's and y's. ?